# How to make a navigation bar work perfect without embedding into a navigation controller?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In iOS7, a UIViewController embedded into a UINavigationController has a navigation bar with 44 height or 64 height automatically. If I don't want to embed my UIViewController into a UINavigationController and I want to add the navigation bar directly in my UIViewController, how can I make the navigation bar work just like the embedding one?

I used auto layout to make the UI like this.

[image: the navigation bar]

As the image showed above, the navigation bar does not cover the status bar's area as expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Make the navigation bar's frame to {0, 0, 320, 64}, then add it as subview as the UIViewController's view.
It should work as your will.